# Push LIVE.COM email doesn't always push new emails

Tags: lumia, email

I have battery saver turned `OFF`, and in email settings `as items arrive`.

Sometimes I receive email immediately and sometimes I have to sync it manually. I have excellent signal and it happens either with `3g` or `2g` network settings (wifi is turned off).

What else should I check to receive push emails? I don't see an option to put mail into background tasks?

**UPDATE:**

It works as expected over wifi, emails are pushed as they arrive. So what is wrong with `2/3g`?

Comment: In the "email+accounts" it shows like it was not sincronized?

Comment: @VitorCanova in `email+accounts` is list of accounts, what exactly am I looking for here?

Comment: If there is a sincronization problem it will show just below the account name with your accent color.

Comment: Forgot to say but I have some situations where I don't receive the pussh immediatelly. But I did receive in some minutes. It says it is sincronized though.

Comment: @VitorCanova no sync error there, I have to do it manually (10 or 15 min after mail arrival).

Comment: Do you notice any difference when on Wifi vs mobile data only?

Comment: @NeilTurner actually it works better over wifi. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with [`APN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name) setting given by provider.

As it seems push mail does not work with **proxy server** and [should be removed](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35133) in order to enable active sync. Also as a side effect, mobile net feels more responsive.